# Organising similar methods withing classes python

Tags: python, class, methods

I am just wondering how i can group similar methods that are within a class in python.
here is an example:

```
class Test:
def add(a, b):
    return a + b
def sub(a, b):
    return a - b
```

i would like to group these functions so that you could call them like this

```
me = Test
print(me.math.add(5, 2))
print(me.math.sub(5, 2))
```

if this is possible. In this case I grouped these function with something called math.
I am not even sure if you can do this but it would be handy

Comment: You could add an attribute or property to your class called `math` that held an object with a bunch of methods on it. It might be a bit confusing though.

Comment: sorry but how would you code that. I am not very experienced with python

Comment: Actually I'm not sure what the purpose of your `Test` class is at all. You're not instantiating it. Are you trying to create a module?

Comment: yes I was but don't worry i know what to do now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?

```py
class Test:
    def __init__(self):
        self.math = Math()

class Math:
    def add(self, a, b):
        return a + b
    def sub(self, a, b):
        return a - b

test = Test()
print(test.math.add(1, 3))
print(test.math.sub(6, 3))
```

Comment: I was just wondering if I wanted to have a method called move(self.x) for example that was in my class would I still be able to group it somehow so that I could reference it by saying    test.motion.move or something like that were the category for the move method would be motion?

Comment: Yes, make another class called motion with a member function move. Then do the same as with the math class in test. You can use self.math.add() and self.motion.move() then.